# Android string link not working with databinding

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to use Databinding in combination with a XML String which has some links and a variable. The problem is that the links do not work anymore, when Databinding is used.

### XML text

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.example.app.framework.ui.viewmodel.EmailViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_standard_agb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@{@string/app_agb(vm.btnText)}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </TextView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I use `android:text="@{@string/app_agb.concat(vm.btnText)}"` I get a NullPointer Exception which is impossible because I use the variable somewhere else and it is 1000% not null. Just using `android:text="@string/app_agb"` works.

### String

```
<string name="app_agb">
    By clicking %1$s you accept the
    <a href="SOME LINK HERE, PRIVAT">privacy policies</a> and
    <a href="SOME LINK HERE, PRIVAT">agbs</a> from example..
</string>
```

### Code in Fragment

```
app_standard_agb.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

### EDIT

Does it make any difference that I include my `app_standard_agb` in my layout?

Comment: find any solution ?

Comment: @RichaShah unfortunately not, but with jetpack compose, this is not a problem anymore. Just switch from databinding to compose and there will be a solution

Answer (score 1):

i think this is because of the `LiveData` doesn't emit Data until it get Observed, so the value of it is null before it get Observed, you can use `@BindingAdapter` and check if the value is not null like following code

put code bellow somewhere in your project(I've tried just in `Kotlin`):

```
@BindingAdapter("android:bindLink")
fun bindLink(view: TextView, link: String?) {
   link?.let{
      view.text = view.context.getString(R.string.app_agb, it)
   }
}
```

and the XML should be like this:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/app_standard_agb"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:linksClickable="true"
   android:bindLink="@{vm.btnText}"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Comment: Nop, this does not work. The text will now be never shown. And my main problem is not that the livedata appears to be null but that my html links do NOT work. P.S: LiveData still null.

Comment: the way you assign the `LiveData` Value in `ViewModel`